# How To WebScrape This Field

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

My code goes into this website and I want only the titles of each row.

My code prints more than the title.

*Example Expected output of row 1 should be - 'Welcome and Introduction of Dr. Hotz'*

This should go on for rows 2, 3 in this format.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

url='https://meetinglibrary.asco.org/session/13399'
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(2)

eachRow=driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[@class='ng-star-inserted']")
for line in eachRow:
   print(line.text)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try finding the rows using div instead.

```py
eachRow=driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='record__title ng-star-inserted']")
```